# Creating raster from several polygon layers using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, classification, overlay

I have the following map:

[image]

The four layers have the following attribute tables:

- **SF_UrbanTreeCanopy_84**

[image]

- **SF_Building_Footprints_84**

[image]

- **GrassBeach**

[image]

- **Water**

[image]

I want to create a raster with the following extent:

Top: 37.822265 dd
Below: 37.708089 dd
Left: -122.522052 dd
Right: -122.351798 dd

That is the extent of the layer `Water` and with `0.00002 decimal degrees` cell size. So the raster should have 5709 rows and 8513 columns. Now:

- Values of the cells that are within `SF_UrbanTreeCanopy_84` should be
  1
- Values of the cells that are within `SF_Building_Footprints_84` should be
  2
- Values of the cells that are within `GrassBeach` should be 3
- Values of the cells that are within `Water` should be 4
- Values of other cells should be 5

That is I want to create a ground truth or a classification map.

Is there any way to do such in ArcGIS 10.3?

Comment: Do the 4 layers intersects ?

Comment: @Shiko No, They don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcGIS has the feature to convert **Polygon to Raster**, and here is the link :
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm

Here are the steps to follow:
(If it is a frequent process, better create a workflow using Model Builder):

1) Convert each file separately using feature mentioned above while setting the **cell value** as you pointed with other options such as cell size and max extent.
2) Use the **Mosaic feature** to combine all Raster layer into one (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm)
3) Finally, to assign value to NoData which is 5 in your case, follow this link:  http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000010059

Answer (score -1):

You can use the feature to raster from conversion tool in ArcGIS and select the field value as Id values. Please go through the link for more details http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! How come you answered the solved question with a duplicate answer — I don't get it?